# $\int_{E} f$ where $f(x, y)=x^{2} y$ and $E$ is the region in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ between the line $y=x-2$ and the parabola $x=4-y^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

- Evaulate the integral $\int_{E} f$ where $f(x, y)=x^{2} y$ and $E$ is the region in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ between the line $y=x-2$ and the parabola $x=4-y^{2}$ Use Funini's thereom

My Attempt. [The graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3Dx-2%20and%20x%3D4-y%5E2)

Then we evaluate $\int_{-2}^{1} \int_{-2-y}^{4-y^2} {x^2y}$ $dx dy.$

**Are the boundeds true?** I think, it shoould be: $\int_{-2}^{1} \int_{2+y}^{4-y^2} {x^2y}$ $dx dy.$ May you check? Thanks...

Comment: It should indeed be $2+y$ instead of $-2-y$. You can note that the two curves are $$x=2+y$$ and $$x=(2+y)(2-y)$$ which intersect only at $(0,-2)$ and $(3,1)$. For $y\in[-2,1]$ we have $$2+y\le (2+y)(2-y)$$ so that this gives a good bound parametrization

Comment: thanks for comment

Comment: Fubini's theorem tells us that $\int_E f$ may be computed by the iterated integrals $\iint_E f(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy$ and $\iint_E f(x,y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx$. This is because $E$ is compact and $f$ continuous, so $f(E)$ is compact and in particular bounded, hence $\int_E f$ exists.

Comment: Thanks for comment...